# Extract text with a Python XPath expression

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I want to display `http:///gb/groceries/easter-essentials--%28approx-205kg%29`.

In `scrapy` I used this XPath expression:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="productNameAndPromotions"]/h3/a/href').extract()
```

but it didn't work!

```
<div class="product ">
    <div class="productInfo">
        <div class="productNameAndPromotions">
            <h3>
                <a href="http:///gb/groceries/easter-essentials--%28approx-205kg%29">
                    <img src="http:co.uk/wcsstore7.20.1.145/ExtendedSitesCatalogAssetStore/image/catalog/productImages/08/020000008_L.jpeg" alt="" />
                </a>
            </h3>
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I completed your XML sample to be _well-formed_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `//div[@class="productNameAndPromotions"]/h3/a/href` means you want to get element `href` which is child of `a`.

If you want to extract nodes' attribute, e.g. `href`, you need to use `@attribute` syntax. Try below:

```
//div[@class="productNameAndPromotions"]/h3/a/@href
```

Comment: Can you share page `URL`?

Comment: thank you @anderson ! i found another solution , but i had another question aboutscrapy how can i convert the list of strings into floats i generated with  (i tried many solutions but doesn't work):                                                                             >>prices_unit = response.xpath('//p[@class="pricePerUnit"]/text()').extract()                                                                                          >>for title in titles:
item["price_unit"] = prices_unit   any help please

Comment: If you get list of strings with `prices_unit = response.xpath('//p[@class="pricePerUnit"]/text()').extract(‌​)` then you can simply get list of floats with `prices_unit = [float(unit) for unit in prices_unit]`

Comment: But you said that `prices_unit` is **list of strings**, right? :) show how does it really looks like- what is output of `print(prices_unit)`?

Comment: It displays prices , if we print prices_unit  {£2.00], £2.50,    £1.00,    £3.00  ...} and i made re.findall to print only numbers {2.00,  2.50, 1.00, 3.00}

Comment: but if i don't make the re.findall and i run your command it says : could not convert string to float: �2.00

Comment: but i made a re.findall to get rid of that

Comment: And it still doesn't work? Does `type(prices_unit)` returns `class 'set'`?

Comment: thank you @Anderson ! it worked i make problem resolved !